# Sort List<Tuple<string, Class>> Alphabetically for the string value of tuple, C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

How can I sort a `list(Tuple<string, class>)` in ascending order for the values of string item of tuple ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var ordered = myList.OrderBy(t => t.Item1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.Item1);
```

Assumes your `string` is in `Item1`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but it wasn't working as expected. I don't know the exact reason. Do I have to assign it to a list ?

Comment: @abhips yes you have to, and also do a `ToList` or `ToArray` to execute it. `OrderBy` is merely a query :)